# How to deal with duplicates with high coefficients of variation

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I am working with raw data from a multiplex Luminex assay ( not by commercial kit); I have found that some duplicates have a high %CV. I would like to know if you can advise me on dealing with this data (I can't remeasure these samples).

I describe some of the solutions I have found:

1.- Choose a cutoff CV and eliminate the duplicates with a higher CV. Some commercial kits recommend a CV of less than 10% to less than 30%.
2.- Consider samples with a high CV, as long as their result is not an outlier, i.e., consistency of the result with a high CV compared to the rest of the data obtained for other biological samples (assess biological consistency ).

I can't entirely agree with the second solution. I think the first approach is more appropriate, but I am new to analyzing this type of data; I am used to working with more accurate results because they do not have the associated biological factor.
I welcome any suggestions.